# p:tabView tab with ui:include src not maintaining seperate tabs

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tabs

I am using primefaces tabview with tabs for separation of data.  When I use the ui:include src to include a data table with a save button on the tab code not in the include src code I get a save button that is not contained within the tab

here is the tab code

```
<p:tab title="Event Costs" disabled="#{eventCreateEditModel.projectEvent.projectEventId==0}">
                    <p:panelGrid id="costsPanelGrid">
                        <ui:include src="eventCreateEditCosts.xhtml"/>
                        <p:row>
                            <p:column colspan="2"> <p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{eventCreateEditModel.update}" update="@form"/></p:column>
                        </p:row>
                    </p:panelGrid>
                </p:tab>
```

and here is the data table code

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

         <p:panel header="Audits List" update="@form" closable="false"  >
            <p:panelGrid  columns="3">
                <p:dataTable value="#{eventCreateEditCostModel.costEntities}" var="eventCost"
                             rowKey="#{eventCost.eventCostId}"
                             sortMode="multiple"
                             resizableColumns="true"
                             widgetVar="eventCostTable"
                              rows="10">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Event Audit Listing
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:column headerText="ID">
                        <h:outputText value="#{eventCost.eventCostId}" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </p:panelGrid>
            </p:panel>
```

The Save button is not contained within the tab but shows outside the tab.

Has anybody seen this type of issue?  Is there another way of including source?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved by only having a include src in the tab.  I had to remove the panelgrid and the row/column with the save button in order for the tabview to work properly.  I put the panelgrid and the save button in the eventCreateEdtCosts.xhtml file.  This defeats my goal of reusable components but does solve the tab display issue.

```
<p:tab title="Event Costs" disabled="#{eventCreateEditModel.projectEvent.projectEventId==0}">
                    <ui:include src="eventCreateEditCosts.xhtml"/>
            </p:tab>
```